# span within span, getting text to appear in a banner on bottom of image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a semi-transparent banner along the bottom portion of each image in this list, but I can get the span inside the image span to work.

I currently have the images set to be full screen as spans in list items which works perfectly, but I can't see the text from my inner span to even test the banner.

What am I. doing wrong?

```css
.slideshow li {
  list-style: none;
}

.slideshow,
.slideshow:after {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 5%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 16s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 16s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 16s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 16s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 16s linear infinite 0s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
  -o-animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

/* Animation for the slideshow images */

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><span style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547937414-009abc449011?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80);"><span style="height:20%; background-color:black; opacity:0.7;">test</span></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547937414-009abc449011?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80);"><span style="height:20%; background-color:black; opacity:0.7;">test</span></span></li>
<li><span style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547937414-009abc449011?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80);"><span style="height:20%; background-color:black; opacity:0.7;">test</span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Isn't the black banner ther on the top of the img? Nothing puts it at the bottom (the li doesn't have a height).

Comment: That's a good point @AHaworth I need to make the li element the height of the image in the span. There's nothing to push it to the bottom yet, I'm just trying to make it to where I can see it to style it